# ionic cordova xmpp Strophe si-filetransfer

Tags: xmpp, cordova-plugins, ionic4, strophe.js

I am developing an ionic-cordova application with chat via Openfire.
I can’t get the si-filetransfer plugin to work

This are the npm packages:

```
"strophe.js": "^1.2.14",
"strophejs-plugin-http-file-upload": "^1.0.3",
"strophejs-plugins": "0.0.7",
```

and this the code in file .ts:

```
  import { Strophe } from 'strophe.js';
  ........

  this.connection.si_filetransfer.addFileHandler(self.fileHandler);
  this.connection.ibb.addIBBHandler(self.ibbHandler);
```

but connection.si_filetransfer’ and ‘connection.ibb’ are always ‘undefined’

How can I import si_filetransfer and make it working?

Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem of include plugins from node modules, with this code works:

```
import { Strophe } from 'strophe.js';
require('strophejs-plugin-http-file-upload');
require('strophejs-plugins/si-filetransfer/strophe.si-filetransfer.js');
require('strophejs-plugins/ibb/strophe.ibb.js');
```